# How do I map a database schema on another?

Tags: mysql, mapping, database-schema, copying

I am trying to migrate a website from one content management system to another. There is a lot of content related data stored in a MySQL database, which will be stored in a different schema in the new database. I would want to somehow map the old schema onto the new and copy the data accordingly. Is there a free tool for such a task - or is there a native MySQL way of doing this?

By free, I mean free as in free beer.

Answer (score 0):

To map data and migrate between two different schema look at ETL like Talend or Pentaho which are "free".

Comment: What makes them "free" and not free?

Comment: @PaulDraper [Open-source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source_software) licenses.

Comment: Hey benek! Thanks for the tip, I shall check them. They very much seem to be what I am looking for. I will give feedback tomorrow.